# How can I use multiple ControlTemplates in a XAML-file?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I'm having this annoying problem with WPF that I can't get my head around.
What I'm trying to create, is a very basic implementation of a drawing program (it's a school assignment) with movable tool windows, like in Photoshop.

I've managed to figure out that I can use this element "Thumb" to implement simple Drag functionality. Since the Thumb element itself is not visible, and the object that I'm using as a container (a DockPanel) does not have a DragDelta property, I simply created a ControlTemplate and attached it to the Thumb, so now I have a draggable color picker that works okay. So far so good.

But, problems arise when I want to create additional ControlTemplates, to use for other Thumb-elements that I plan to use (I get the error: The property 'VisualTree' is set more than once.).
This is what I want help with. I have pasted my whole Window.Resources-tag here so you can see what's going on.

```xml
<Window.Resources>          
        <Style x:Key="toolBoxBtn" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="60" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="60" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="style1" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">

                        <DockPanel Background="#e6e6e6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" Height="auto" Width="auto" Canvas.Left="640" Canvas.Top="8">
                            <Label VerticalAlignment="Top" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="#282828" Foreground="white" Content="Colors" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="auto" Height="auto" />

                            <StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="7" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Rectangle DockPanel.Dock="top" Name="red" Fill="Red" Height="20" Width="20" Stroke="Black" MouseDown="getColor" />
                                    <Rectangle DockPanel.Dock="top" Name="blue" Fill="Blue" Height="20" Width="20" Stroke="Black" MouseDown="getColor"/>
                                    <Rectangle DockPanel.Dock="top" Name="green" Fill="GreenYellow" Height="20" Width="20" Stroke="Black" MouseDown="getColor"/>

                                    <Rectangle DockPanel.Dock="top" Name="customColorSlot1" Fill="White" Height="20" Width="20" Stroke="Black" MouseDown="getColor" />
                                    <Rectangle DockPanel.Dock="top" Name="customColorSlot2" Fill="White" Height="20" Width="20" Stroke="Black" MouseDown="getColor"/>
                                    <Rectangle DockPanel.Dock="top" Name="customColorSlot3" Fill="White" Height="20" Width="20" Stroke="Black" MouseDown="getColor"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <GroupBox Header="Selected Color">
                                    <Rectangle Name="currentColor" Fill="White" Height="40" Width="40" Stroke="Black" MouseDown="test"/>
                                </GroupBox>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DockPanel>

                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="fillTool" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                        <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" Margin="310,330,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="19" Fill="Blue"/>
                        <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="12" Margin="317,316,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="12" Fill="Blue"/>
                        <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="8" Margin="307,320,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="7" Fill="Blue"/>
                        <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="3" Margin="317,302,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="3" Fill="Blue"/>
                        <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="5" Margin="311,310,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="5" Fill="Blue"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>
```

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ControlTemplate` can only contain one child. Try and change it to a `Canvas` instead

```
        <Style x:Key="fillTool" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                        <Canvas>
                           <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" Margin="310,330,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="19" Fill="Blue"/>
                           <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="12" Margin="317,316,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="12" Fill="Blue"/>
                           <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="8" Margin="307,320,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="7" Fill="Blue"/>
                           <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="3" Margin="317,302,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="3" Fill="Blue"/>
                           <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="5" Margin="311,310,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="5" Fill="Blue"/>
                        </Canvas>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```